# Electron fails to open window when registering a service worker

Tags: webpack, electron, service-worker

I am building an electron app and wanted to add a service worker.
The app is built with Webpack. For some reason, this code fails:

```
import swURL from 'file-loader!./serviceWorker'

navigator.serviceWorker.register(swURL, {scope: './'})
```

I see the asset being outputted by WebPack properly. But, the window does not open and I can not see any error. Not even using `DEBUG="*"`.

Any idea?

Comment: electron -> webpack -> service worker -> require = headache ^^ check this https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-remote , read the issue about webpack and prepare for war ! hope it helps

Comment: Service workers are entirely client side, while the library you mentioned has to do with inter process communication. I fail to see how this can help me?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the service worker?

Comment: I want to cache data that I get from a rest API so that it can be used offline. With Electron I could do it differently but this app can be hosted too. I have no problem with service workers, just this issue in Electron. I am not trying to find a workaround to my actual business problem. I'd like to make service worker properly work in an Electron app in general. I have read some blog posts but there are little mentions to these problems. I only found this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9663

Comment: try rewriting the import statement with Require instead and full path  check if it was registred by opening this url with electron chrome://serviceworker-internals/. if it is registered then something is wrong with the code inside the serviceWorker file

Comment: Since the window does not open, I can not check such url. Plus the content of the service worker so far has "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

Delete these two lines , once you can open electron , open the console and type this

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./serviceWorker', 
    {})
```

Don't forget to change the path if you get a path error , once it's done select  this url `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` with the mouse grab it and drop it on the electron window .

Comment: Thank you for trying to help :) I tried something like that. What happens is the browser "kind of" crashes, becomes irresponsible, the devtools get a semiopaque white layer with a popup saying that "DevTools were disconnected from the page." I am making a repo with minimal test case.

Comment: try to update electron globally and remove reinstall your modules , because on my machine , it works (windows 8.1)